# Ctrl + R alternative for Guake

Tags: search, guake

I have been a heavy user of `reverse-search-history`( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ) functionality in `gnome-terminal`(Default terminal client in  Ubuntu). Recently I started using [Guake](http://guake.org/) drop-down terminal in my system. Loved Guake for its easy access, but couldn't find any `revere-search-history` functionality or key-mapping for it. Is there such a thing available for Guake, or is there any workaround solutions for it?

Comment: I can confirm that CTRL+R brings up the same prompt in Guake as it does in Gnome Terminal for me. Try reinstalling Guake, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Alex's comment. It made me delve into the Guake preferences in which, the `Default interpreter` was set as `/bin/dash`.
I just had to change it to: `/bin/bash`, now all my bash settings set in my `.bashrc` file works, along with the `reverse-search-history`( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ).

Change in Guake Preferences:
[image: Guake Preferences]

Guake now works as intended:
[image: Guake with reverse-history-search]

Comment: I like the background on guake you use. 
I wasn't able to find the image, please provide a link to it . <br/>

Comment: @user182904, Let me check if I still have that wallpaper with me. I had found it from some `mimnimalist wallpaper` site.

Comment: thnx,  I found the image here http://wallpoper.com/images/00/35/79/49/black-minimalistic_00357949.jpg.
But background just goes black, no bulbs on the right, have you done any tweaking other than just setting image background from guake preferences??

Comment: @user182904, I don't remember exactly. I'll check and tell.